# Connected components to detect text

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, connected-components

I'am reading an article about Layout analysis, and I want to code the method using Python and Opencv.

In the article, he used a the connected components method to detect letters of text after that doing some traitements to extract all layouts.

So, I'm trying to do this on python, and I used connectedComponentsWithStats function of Opencv to get the connected components.

```py
image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image_threshold = cv2.threshold(image_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image_threshold, connectivity=8)

for i in range(0, nb_components):
    x_min = stats[i, 0]
    y_min = stats[i, 1]
    x_max = stats[i, 0] + stats[i, 2]
    y_max = stats[i, 1] + stats[i, 3]

    cv2.rectangle(self.image, (x_min, y_min), (x_max, y_max), (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

So I want to get result like this:

[image: all the connected components are detected]

but I get something like this where just the round components are detected:

[image: just the round components are detected]

Original Image
[image: Original Image]

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. But, are you inputting the image in negative? I think that could explain it.

Comment: I add all the code

Comment: Could you add the original image?

Comment: I added the original image